# Is there a way to auto scroll a listbox in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listboxitem

I am writing a program that will display a list of numbers in several list boxes on a big monitor. Is there a way to auto-scroll the list box to show all the data in the boxes?

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? WinForm, ASP.Net, WPF ?

Comment: lots of working examples are online @Evanark if you are familiar with EventHandlers and static methods creation...this can all be done very easily..

Comment: when you select an intem from the listbox (via `listBox.SelectedIndex = number;` or `listBox.SelectedItem = "string";`), the listbox is automatically scrolled to the selected item.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485196/autoscrolling-a-listbox-under-a-certain-situation)

Answer (score 9):

Normally, I would do:

```
listBox.SelectedIndex = listBox.Items.Count - 1;
listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

but you can also try

```
int nItems = (int)(listBox.Height / listBox.ItemHeight);
listBox.TopIndex = listBox.Items.Count - nItems;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear in my description what I mean was giving list box a marquee effect :) Having the data auto scroll down then repeat.

Comment: The second option will not work if the draw mode is set to `UserDrawVariable`. In such a case you'll need to call `GetItemHeight` starting from the last item index and do the math.

Answer (score 3):

To directly control the scrolling without selecting items, you need to use the Win32 `SetScrollPos` method from `User32.dll`. Here is a extended class which gives you basic support:

```
public class ScrollableListView : ListView
{
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

    private enum ScrollBar : int { Horizontal = 0x0, Vertical = 0x1 }

    public void SetScroll(int x, int y)
    {
        this.SetScroll(ScrollBar.Horizontal, x);
        this.SetScroll(ScrollBar.Vertical, y);
    }

    public void SetScrollX(int position)
    {
        this.SetScroll(ScrollBar.Horizontal, position);
    }

    public void SetScrollY(int position)
    {
        this.SetScroll(ScrollBar.Vertical, position);
    }

    [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

    private void SetScroll(ScrollBar bar, int position)
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
        {
            ScrollableListView.SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, (int)bar, position, true);
            ScrollableListView.PostMessage((IntPtr)this.Handle, ScrollableListView.WM_VSCROLL, 4 + 0x10000 * position, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then set the X or Y scroll quickly and easily. This should work for other controls too.

---

If you want to make the control automatically scroll down and up, you would need to set up a recurring timer, with an interval of around 20 milliseconds. Keep track of the scroll position and direction, and increment or decrement it accordingly, sending the position to the control using these methods.

---

**UPDATE:**

I had a few problems with the SetScrollPos method posted above, primarily around the scrollbar moving, but the contents not. It's probably just a minor oversight, but in the meantime, here is a somewhat "outside the box" MarqueeListView solution..

First up, the enum representing which scrollbar to use. I used display names instead of the Win32 names for these (`SB_HORIZ` and `SB_VERT`) just to make things a little clearer.

```
public enum ScrollBarDirection : int { Horizontal = 0x0, Vertical = 0x1 }
```

Another enum for the scroll command codes themselves - I've trimmed out everything apart from Up (`SB_LINEUP`), Down (`SB_LINEDOWN`) and EndScroll (`SB_ENDSCROLL`). EndScroll is needed after the scroll message to inform the control to update.

```
public enum ScrollCommand : int { Up = 0x0, Down = 0x1, EndScroll = 0x8 }
```

Then finally the class itself. It basically starts by scrolling down, every 20ms (by default - note this is changeable via the MarqueeSpeed property). It then gets the scroll position, and compares it to last time. Once the scroll bar stops moving, it reverses the direction. This is to get around problems I was having with the `GetScrollInfo` method.

```
public class MarqueeListView : ListView
{
    protected const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

    private ScrollCommand scrollCommand;
    private int scrollPositionOld;
    private Timer timer;

    public MarqueeListView()
        : base()
    {
        this.MarqueeSpeed = 20;

        this.scrollPositionOld = int.MinValue;
        this.scrollCommand = ScrollCommand.Down;

        this.timer = new Timer() { Interval = this.MarqueeSpeed };
        this.timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            int scrollPosition = MarqueeListView.GetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.Vertical);
            if (scrollPosition == this.scrollPositionOld)
            {
                if (this.scrollCommand == ScrollCommand.Down)
                {
                    this.scrollCommand = ScrollCommand.Up;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.scrollCommand = ScrollCommand.Down;
                }
            }
            this.scrollPositionOld = scrollPosition;

            MarqueeListView.SendMessage((IntPtr)this.Handle, MarqueeListView.WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)this.scrollCommand, IntPtr.Zero);
            MarqueeListView.SendMessage((IntPtr)this.Handle, MarqueeListView.WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)ScrollCommand.EndScroll, IntPtr.Zero);
        };
        this.timer.Start();
    }

    public int MarqueeSpeed
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timer.Interval;
        }
        set
        {
            this.timer.Interval = value;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    protected static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Finally, here's a quick Main method to test it:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form form = new Form() { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen, Width = 1280, Height = 720 };
        MarqueeListView list = new MarqueeListView() { View = View.Tile, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { list.Items.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); }
        form.Controls.Add(list);

        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

Please bear in mind, this isn't necessarily the "proper" or best way of doing things, but I figured a different approach might give you some ideas!

I was hoping to use `SetScrollPos` which would give a much better, smoother effect. You can then easily include acceleration and deceleration - possibly optionally slowing to a halt on mouse over, then accelerating away on mouse out etc. It's just not playing ball at present though - I've got a working scroll update method in an old project somewhere, so I'll update this if I get it working again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess what I want is to select the first item and have code run to select the next item and so until it reached the end of the list then have it repeat. I am still a newbie so I am not sure how to apply the code you posted.

Comment: Rather than selecting the items, this code allows you to simulate the windows messages that are raised when you scroll the control, such as with the mouse wheel. It may be preferable if you still want to be able to select the items manually. I'll update it with some code to automatically scroll the control up and down shortly.

Comment: Cool I'll give this a go and see what happens. Thanks! Ill let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Question which class does the enums go, and which class do I used, the marqueeListView class or the the scrollable list view class? I am curious try this method instead of the timer and selectedindex method.

Comment: The enums can go directly into the namespace just like the classes. You then create a `MarqueeListView` if you want the auto scrolling enabled.

Comment: You can also check out [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `SelectedIndex`. It does have another problem though - if the ListView is using one of the icon or tile views, it can be hard to control the speed, as it will cycle across the items as well as down - hence the Win32 scroll message approach.

Comment: Can this be used for a listBox

Comment: Yes indeed - just about any control :)

Answer (score 2):

Even if it was a long time ago, others will certainly have the same problem. Since selecting the last item did not lead to automatic scrolling for me, here is a solution that works for me:

```
ListBox1.ScrollIntoView(ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.Items.Count - 1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or just insert your items at the top by using:
`lbLog.Items.Insert(0,"LogItem");`